# Special invisible frames in the beginning of the avi-files. How to recognize/handle them correctly?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, codec, avi

I wrote simple video editing software, it just splits video by keyframes and nothing more. It works fine, until I found 1 strange file.

Here exists 1 "invisible frame" with 2 NALs: SPS and PPS. If I remove this single frame, whole other file is unreadable. Other frames marked as keyframes, but not have this SPS and PPS headers.

[image: strange file]

If you look at a normal file encoded with the same codec, then you see these special headers are included in each keyframe:

[image: good file]

Since my program just took and cut the frames from the beginning of the file, then such a file just stopped working! I try to do the same with ffmpeg:

```
      ffmpeg -ss 10:00 -i file.avi -c copy -t 10 out.avi
```

And also got broken file!

I checked reference for AVI files and don't see here any notes about special handling of such invisible frames. What I should read/do to handle such files properly?

Answer (score 1):

If the stream was originally generated for a container with global headers, then SPS/PPS will be missing from remaining keyframe packets.

You can use a bitstream filter to insert them.

```
ffmpeg -ss 10:00 -i file.avi -c copy -bsf:v dump_extra=k -t 10 out.avi
```

Comment: I must know how to handle it properly in my own software. Yes, I can see first first frame, but I don't think what it right way.

Comment: Then check the source of the bsf to see how to detect and insert extradata.

Comment: ffmpeg don't detect it anyway. What about other codecs?

Answer (score 1):

SPS and PPS are required for decoding all following frames. Your editing software will need to keep track of the last IDR keyframe and it's associated SPS/PPS and decode from there. One method would be to buffer the most recent prior SPS/PPS and send it to the decoder just before you decode the IDR keyframe.

Comment: This is very specific for h264 only. I try to find more generic way, which will work for all codecs. Unfortunately I can't find any clues in AVI spec about such behavior.

Comment: I believe you must handle each codec in it's specific way. AVI is just a "container" format for H.264. The example you gave is an AVI container file with H.264 data. See: http://www.iorgsoft.com/compare/avi-vs-h.264-comparison.html

Comment: I'm not sure that I have enough of my life to write code for all possible codecs on this planet. I just want to write a program that simply divides the video file.